# Encrypt Windows Backup

Tags: security, encryption, backup

Is there a way to encrypt my backups using Windows Backup in Server 2008 R2 without using a paid for 3rd party application?  I've searched high and low but have been unable to find anything.

Thanks in advance!
msindle

Comment: I've never done it, but I'd presume that you could enable bitlocker on whatever external drive or dedicated volume you are backing up to.

Comment: How about using a TrueCrypt volume as your backup destination?

Comment: @jlehtinen We've looked at using TrueCrypt, but I cant find a guide on how that should be set up.  Otherwise i'm not sure how it would work either?

Comment: @msindle TrueCrypt makes an encrypted file and mounts it as a virtual disk. You can create TrueCrypt volumes anywhere you could normally create/store a file (local disk, network shares, cloud services, etc.).  http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/tutorial

Comment: @jlehtinen So what I'm gathering from that link is I create the encrypted folder and just point windows backup to backup to that folder?

Comment: @msindle Yep, that should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Enable bitlocker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766295%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on the backup target.

**Update:** You can manage auto-unlock via the Bitlocker admin page or [Manage-Bde.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff829846.aspx).  If the host is not using Bitlocker, you cannot use auto-unlock, but you can use the [`-unlock` option](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff829854.aspx) to explicitly unlock a drive from a script.

**Note:** I would only recommend Bitlocker if the target drive is a flash drive or hard disk.  Something like Tape or any WORM disk would not fare as well.

Comment: Have you actually done this before? Bitlocker can only be used on non-removable devices. Bitlocker To Go can be used on removable media, but I imagine that if you're using tape, it will be a nightmare. Not to mention that it would lock the backup target such as a USB disk or tape to the one server it was encrypted on if you leverage the TPM. If you don't leverage the TPM, you need to enter the pass phrase before each and every backup - a nightmare for automation. I've never used Bitlocker this way, so I'd love to be proven wrong if you've actually done this before.

Comment: I have done this, actually.  Bitlocker-to-go can be used on removable hard disks and be scripted to unlock automatically.  If the intent is to ensure the backup disk is unreadable if stolen in transit (which given that the server is not encrypted, I am guessing is the case), having the key in cleartext in the script is fine.

Comment: @MDMarra, Also, the concern about using the disk on multiple servers is unneeded.  The TPM module does not contain the actual drive key, but just decrypts the drive key.  You can use a disk running bitlocker-to-go on multiple systems while still leveraging TPM.  You will have to enter the passphrase the first time, but it can thereafter be auto-unlocked.

Comment: +1 - I'm doing this, too. The intention was to allow storage of the backup disks (removable USB 3.0 drives) in a location where, if they were stolen, the thief wouldn't get anything more than a disk out of the deal.

Comment: @EvanAnderson: That's exactly what I am planning to do. Now, 7 years later... any downsides, lessons-learned or anything else I should be aware of? Obviously, I'll store the printed-out recovery keys at a (really) safe place.

Comment: @heinzi, not really. It just… works. Since this was written, Bitlocker support has been [added for Linux](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker/tree/develop), which can be useful in pre-boot restores.  I’ve also used this technique against bitlocker encrypted vhd’s, then moved them to the cloud for archival.

Comment: @EvanAnderson: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to hear.

Comment: Unfortunately, auto-unlock only works after a user *actually logs in*, which might be undesirable for a server. These are the steps I took to make auto-unlock work without logging in: (1) Disable auto-login, if you enabled it. (2) Add a protector with is stored in active directory: `manage-bde z: -protectors -add -sid YourDomain\Administrator`. This user can now lock/unlock the drive with `manage-bde -lock z:` and `manage-bde -unlock z: -sid` without needing a password. (3) Put the latter (unlock) command in a planned task running with that user account right before backup starts.

Answer (score 0):

[7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org) can do it. It supports several operating systems.

Comment: How would 7-zip do this?